# Collect EventLogs from remote XP machines

Tags: windows, windows-xp, event-log, administration

I want to collate EventLogs from different machines onto one machine. Is there any way that this can be done non-programatically using Windows XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is no automatic way to do that provided by system. You could use Remote Desktop or SSH to access machines, but You will have to connect and retrieve logs from every machine manually.

Of course You can make your own program to do this for You.